# Crash after BottomNavigation click while animation is still fading in/out

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, bottomnavigationview, fragment-animation

I have BottomNavigation and 4 fragments. The App crashes after I click on the BottomNavigation symbols but only if the animation (fade in/out) is still in process. If I disable the animation in my code like shown: /*setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).*/ everything works fine but without animation of course. I would like to keep the animation. How can I solve this, please?

This is my BottomNavigation code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_Navigation_View);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_partOne);
}

partOne partOneFragment = new partOne();
partTwo partTwoFragment = new partTwo();
partThree partThreeFragment = new partThree();
partFour partFourFragment = new partFour();

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.navigation_partOne:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()./*setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).*/replace(R.id.container, partOneFragment).commit();
            return true;

        case R.id.navigation_partTwo:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()./*setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).*/replace(R.id.container, partTwoFragment).commit();
            return true;

        case R.id.navigation_partThree:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()./*setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).*/replace(R.id.container, partThreeFragment).commit();
            return true;

        case R.id.navigation_partFour:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()./*setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).*/replace(R.id.container, partFourFragment).commit();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
}
```

For the sake of completeness this is my fade_in.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:duration="300"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

Error in Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.exerciseexample, PID: 17519
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Restarter must be created only during owner's initialization stage
        at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryController.performRestore(SavedStateRegistryController.java:58)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2585)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:838)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

`compileSdkVersion` is 29; relevant dependency is `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'`: I've already tried by downgrading those versions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539251/backstack-management-restarter-must-be-created-only-during-owners-initializat

Comment: @noureldienmohamed I've already tried the accepted answer as written in my question. I am new: what exactly should I try, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add AddToBackStack(null) after setCustomAnimations() for each fragment.

```
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, 
 R.anim.fade_out).AddToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.container, 
  partOneFragment).commit();
```

Another solution you can try to change the library version to androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2.

Comment: It doesn't crash anymore. This is good. But now BackPress means it doesn't leave the App but it follows back the path I've clicked on, which is bad. For example: I click partOneFragment, then partTwo, then partThree --> Clicking Backpress now means I go again to partTwo, then partOne, then it leaves the app.